# Elastic Search setup using Kubernetes

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes

I have a Elastic search setup.

I need to deploy the same in kubernetes

Purpose : Automatically scale up the ES server with all its data to 3 instances if the CPU/RAM reaches 90% and scale it down to one instance with all its data

Using `ReplicationController` scaling  can be possible

I need , How to setup ES with all it's current data in kubernetes

Can anyone help me on this out?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to ask: do you have existing applications in your cluster that have to deal with **persistent storage**, or is ES going to be the first? Because storage is one of those sharp-edged things in a kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 1):

You will want [`StatefulSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)s ([tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/)) for part of that problem (they honor `kubectl scale sts --replicas=$foo`, just like an `rc`)

Having members with predictable hostnames (as a `StatefulSet` will do) makes the `discovery.zen.ping.hostnames` a ton easier to configure -- even if there is only one ES node actually alive at the time (that is: you can specify `my-es-0.my-es.my-ns.svc.cluster.local,my-es-1.my-es.my-ns.svc.cluster.local,etc` in the `zen` list, and the first ES node will whine, but the 2nd and upward will benefit from the actual *discovery* part)

> scale it down to one instance with all its data

Good luck with that; you'd have to re-balance the shards of every index with each resizing operation, since ES wants to distribute the load out across all members of its cluster -- the exact opposite of your consolidation objective.

I'd bet you could make a custom Horizontal Pod Autoscaler implementation that waited until the rebalancing operations had completed before destroying the Pods, but I'm not aware right now of any out-of-the-box mechanism for doing that.